# Color Highlighter doesn't work on Sublime Text 3 Win 10

Tags: css, sublimetext3

I installed the color highlighter package and it just doesn't seem to work.
I've tried restarting sublime, reinstalling the package and other methods like renaming the package name as suggested in other threads but still doesn't work.

[My Project Snip, You can see the package installed in the next tab not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YviQD.png)

```
DPI mode: per-monitor v2
startup, version: 3176 windows x64 channel: stable
executable: /C/Program Files/Sublime Text 3/sublime_text.exe
working dir: /C/Program Files/Sublime Text 3
packages path: /C/Users/ASUS/AppData/Roaming/Sublime Text 3/Packages
state path: /C/Users/ASUS/AppData/Roaming/Sublime Text 3/Local
zip path: /C/Program Files/Sublime Text 3/Packages
zip path: /C/Users/ASUS/AppData/Roaming/Sublime Text 3/Installed Packages
ignored_packages: ["Vintage"]
pre session restore time: 0.0725516
startup time: 0.103552
first paint time: 0.119552
reloading plugin Default.arithmetic
reloading plugin Default.auto_indent_tag
reloading plugin Default.block
reloading plugin Default.colors
reloading plugin Default.comment
reloading plugin Default.convert_color_scheme
reloading plugin Default.convert_syntax
reloading plugin Default.copy_path
reloading plugin Default.delete_word
reloading plugin Default.detect_indentation
reloading plugin Default.duplicate_line
reloading plugin Default.echo
reloading plugin Default.exec
reloading plugin Default.fold
reloading plugin Default.font
reloading plugin Default.goto_line
reloading plugin Default.history_list
reloading plugin Default.indentation
reloading plugin Default.install_package_control
reloading plugin Default.kill_ring
reloading plugin Default.mark
reloading plugin Default.new_templates
reloading plugin Default.open_context_url
reloading plugin Default.open_in_browser
reloading plugin Default.pane
reloading plugin Default.paragraph
reloading plugin Default.paste_from_history
reloading plugin Default.profile
reloading plugin Default.quick_panel
reloading plugin Default.rename
reloading plugin Default.run_syntax_tests
reloading plugin Default.save_on_focus_lost
reloading plugin Default.scroll
reloading plugin Default.set_unsaved_view_name
reloading plugin Default.settings
reloading plugin Default.show_scope_name
reloading plugin Default.side_bar
reloading plugin Default.sort
reloading plugin Default.swap_line
reloading plugin Default.switch_file
reloading plugin Default.symbol
reloading plugin Default.transform
reloading plugin Default.transpose
reloading plugin Default.trim_trailing_white_space
reloading plugin Default.ui
reloading plugin CSS.css_completions
reloading plugin Diff.diff
reloading plugin HTML.encode_html_entities
reloading plugin HTML.html_completions
reloading plugin ShellScript.ShellScript
reloading plugin 0_package_control_loader.00-package_control
reloading plugin Color Highlighter.color_converter
reloading plugin Color Highlighter.color_highlighter
reloading plugin Color Highlighter.color_hover_listener
reloading plugin Color Highlighter.color_scheme
reloading plugin Color Highlighter.color_scheme_color_highlighter
reloading plugin Color Highlighter.color_searcher
reloading plugin Color Highlighter.color_selection_listener
reloading plugin Color Highlighter.colors
reloading plugin Color Highlighter.content_listener
reloading plugin Color Highlighter.convert_color_command
reloading plugin Color Highlighter.css_colors
reloading plugin Color Highlighter.dummy_event_listener
reloading plugin Color Highlighter.gutter_icons_color_highlighter
reloading plugin Color Highlighter.load_resource
reloading plugin Color Highlighter.main
reloading plugin Color Highlighter.path
reloading plugin Color Highlighter.phantoms_color_highlighter
reloading plugin Color Highlighter.pick_color_command
reloading plugin Color Highlighter.regex_compiler
reloading plugin Color Highlighter.regions
reloading plugin Color Highlighter.set_setting_command
reloading plugin Color Highlighter.settings
reloading plugin Color Highlighter.st_helper
reloading plugin Color Highlighter.topsort
reloading plugin ImageMagick.SublimeMagick
reloading plugin Package Control.1_reloader
reloading plugin Package Control.2_bootstrap
reloading plugin Package Control.Package Control
plugins loaded
Traceback: error.

Output:


Error:
Invalid Parameter - TrueColorMatte


Highlighting colors with gutter icons is not supported with current ImageMagick setup. Try configuring the "icon_factory setting"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3\sublime_plugin.py", line 283, in on_api_ready
    m.plugin_loaded()
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Installed Packages\Color Highlighter.sublime-package\main.py", line 606, in plugin_loaded
    ColorHighlighterPlugin.init()
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Installed Packages\Color Highlighter.sublime-package\main.py", line 319, in init
    ColorHighlighterPlugin._fake_color_scheme = ColorHighlighterPlugin.components.provide_fake_color_scheme()
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Installed Packages\Color Highlighter.sublime-package\main.py", line 197, in provide_fake_color_scheme
    return self.provide_fake_color_scheme_data()[0]
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Installed Packages\Color Highlighter.sublime-package\main.py", line 188, in provide_fake_color_scheme_data
    self._fake_color_scheme_data = parse_color_scheme(self.provide_color_scheme(), self._settings.debug)
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Installed Packages\Color Highlighter.sublime-package\color_scheme.py", line 40, in parse_color_scheme
    color_scheme_content = load_resource.load_resource(color_scheme)
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Installed Packages\Color Highlighter.sublime-package\load_resource.py", line 30, in load_resource
    return sublime.load_resource(file_path)
  File "C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3\sublime.py", line 192, in load_resource
    raise IOError("resource not found")
OSError: resource not found
Package Control: Skipping automatic upgrade, last run at 2018-06-21 10:46:14, next run at 2018-06-21 11:46:14 or after
```

A copy of my console output if it helps.